# How can I adjust keyboard backlight on the new M1 MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, apple-silicon

The 2020 M1 Macbook Air lacks keys to adjust keyboard brightness and <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> don’t appear to have any effect.

Is there a way to adjust - especially to turn off - the keyboard backlight?

[image: MacBook Air 2020 (Winter, M1) F-key layout]

Comment: I had the same problem mentioned above, and it concerned me that Apple did not add a shortcut to adjust this. So, I have developed an application that adds the following shortcuts in place: “fn + F2” to brighten backlight, and “fn + F1” to darken backlight. Take a look over at https://naden.co/luminescent.html

Answer (score 121, accepted):

From Control Center, choose Keyboard Brightness and adjust the slider.

[image: Screen recording of instructions.]

Comment: Can't find the button by default on MacOS 13.1. I had to go to "System Settings" -> "Control Centre", under "Other Modules" and turn on "Show in Control Centre" for Keyboard Brightness.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to be able to adjust the keyboard backlight with <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> again, you can install Karabiner-Elements to remap the keys. This worked for me on an M1 Macbook Air (2020), running macOS 11.2.1 Big Sur, and the version of Karabiner-Elements I have right now is 13.3.0.

1. Install with Homebrew

   ```bsh
   brew install karabiner-elements
   ```
2. Open Karabiner-Elements. The icon looks like this:

   [image: Karabiner-Elements icon]
3. Since it needs to see your keystrokes and modify them, you'll need to enable some accessibility permissions. I can't remember exactly which, but you should be prompted to enable them when you open the app.
4. With Karabiner-Elements open, click on the "Function keys" tab, and set `f5` to `illumination_down` and `f6` to `illumination_up`. Uncheck "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" if it's checked.

   [image: screenshot of Karabiner-Elements preferences pane]
5. <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> should now *attempt* to change the the keyboard brightness, but they don't always work, and sometimes you get an icon with a  flash on the screen (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/2645) for details). Oddly enough, whether it works or not depends on the ambient lighting in the room. To fix this, you need to disable the "Adjust keyboard brightness in low light" setting. Go to the macOS keyboard preferences menu (System Preferences > Keyboard), and uncheck it.

   [image]

   You may notice in the screenshot that the "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" option is checked here. It doesn't appear to have any effect whether it is checked or not, but the setting in Karabiner-Elements *does* matter.

Answer (score 7):

Apple supports a official way to remap the old style by f5/f6 keys!

It was the first thing which i've changed on a new M2 MacBook. I have no needs for the original keymappings to microphone or sleep, so i found this solution is very handy if you know this keys from older Apple Devices and can live by the misslabled Keysymbols. Found this solution on Reddit¹

Create a new plist file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` named `com.local.KeyRemapping.plist` and add the code below. Save the file and reboot. F5 and F6 will now work as keyboard brightness up/down keys (after you log in for the first time after rebooting).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.local.KeyRemapping</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/hidutil</string>
        <string>property</string>
        <string>--set</string>
        <string>{"UserKeyMapping":[
            {
              "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc": 0xC000000CF,
              "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst": 0xFF00000009
            },
            {
              "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc": 0x10000009B,
              "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst": 0xFF00000008
            }
        ]}</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

There exists also Web-Editors to generate more functions on keys²

And under Link 3 is an Apple Developer Link for more Infos about Keycodes.

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/jy5ry8/m1_macbook_air_keysshortcut_for_keyboard/
2. https://hidutil-generator.netlify.app/
3. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

For new MacOS `Settings -> Control Center -> Keyboard Brightness`

Switch on the necessary controls
[image]

Now you can control the keyboard brightness from the control center (top right corner of the Screen)
[image]