# Assign keyboard shortcuts for adjusting keyboard brightness

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I have a MacBook Air (M1, 2020) and one of the few things I don't like about it is that it does not have dedicated function keys for increasing/decreasing the keyboard backlight brightness.  I know that I can control the keyboard brightness from the Control Center, and that [I can place a brightness controller on the menu bar. I also know that I can use Karabiner Elements to remap existing function keys to keyboard brightness up and down](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408359/how-can-i-adjust-keyboard-backlight-on-the-new-m1-macbook-air).

But what I *want* to do is create custom keyboard shortcuts -- say, for example, <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd>  -- for this purpose, without eliminating the existing defaults.

Is there a way to do that, either using Karabiner or some other tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/), you can import a `complex_modifications rule` named [Keyboard Brightness Adjustment](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#keyboard-brightness), it enables that:

> command-f1 and f2 to adjust keyboard brightness

You can also customize the keys:

1. Open the [Keyboard Brightness Adjustment](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#keyboard-brightness) page, select "Copy JSON URL" from the drop list beside the "Import" button.
2. Open the [JSON URL](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/json/keyboard-brightness.json) in browser, save it as a file which named `keyboard-brightness.json`.
3. Open `keyboard-brightness.json` with a plan text editor (e.g. [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/)), find all of the `command` and replace them with `shift`, save the file.
4. Copy your amazing JSON file into `~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/`, then import rules from Karabiner-Elements Preferences:

> `Karabiner-Elements` > `Preferences` > `Complex Modifications` > `Add rule` > `Enable` your rule - `shift-f1 and f2 to adjust keyboard brightness`

Then it should work.

If you have other rules, move the rule to the top by dragging the `⇅` icon to make sure it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem mentioned above, and it concerned me that Apple **did not add a shortcut** to adjust this. So, I have developed an application that adds the following shortcuts in place: <kbd>Fn/</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>  **brighten** backlight, and <kbd>Fn/</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> **darken** backlight. Take a look over at https://naden.co/luminescent.html